# Using singular vs. plural objects in a prepositional phrase

Tags: syntax

What are the grammatical differences between:

> He's good at driving **cars**.

and:

> He's good at driving **a car**.

Are there any differences in correctness or meaning, or times when you should use one form over the other?

Comment: Both are grammatically correct.  It depends on what, exactly, you are trying to say.  Can you please add more detail?

Comment: Agreed, a bit more detail would be necessary to draw a distinction. They both mean extremely similar things, and are both correct. There would be few situations where one is clearly preferable.

Answer (score 1):

I think they are the same, unless it is salient whether there is a multiplicity of cars.  So, if his entire car driving experience was from practicing with just a single car, even though he's a very good driver, one might still be hesitant to say "he's good at driving cars", for want of any direct evidence on whether he can handle another car.